# R - fill value based on conditions in Person Period Format

Tags: r

I am struggling to find a simple way to fill values based on two simple conditions.

I am trying to fill the variable `working` with `1` after the first and last "`1`" for each `dayweek`. The example is more telling.

```
    id hours dayweek working
1   1     1  Friday       0
2   1     2  Friday       0
3   1     3  Friday       0
4   1     4  Friday       0
5   1     5  Friday       0
6   1     6  Friday       0
7   1     7  Friday       0
8   1     8  Friday       1
9   1     9  Friday       0
10  1    10  Friday       0
11  1    11  Friday       0
12  1    12  Friday       0
13  1    13  Friday       0
14  1    14  Friday       0
15  1    15  Friday       0
16  1    16  Friday       0
17  1    17  Friday       1
18  1    18  Friday       0
19  1    19  Friday       0
20  1    20  Friday       0
```

I am trying to do this.

```
    id hours dayweek working
1   1     1  Friday       0
2   1     2  Friday       0
3   1     3  Friday       0
4   1     4  Friday       0
5   1     5  Friday       0
6   1     6  Friday       0
7   1     7  Friday       0
8   1     8  Friday       1
9   1     9  Friday       1
10  1    10  Friday       1
11  1    11  Friday       1
12  1    12  Friday       1
13  1    13  Friday       1
14  1    14  Friday       1
15  1    15  Friday       1
16  1    16  Friday       1
17  1    17  Friday       1
18  1    18  Friday       0
19  1    19  Friday       0
20  1    20  Friday       0
```

The `group_by` must be `id` and `dayweek`.

Any clue ?

The data

```
structure(list(id = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("1", 
"2", "3"), class = "factor"), hours = 1:20, dayweek = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Friday", "Monday", "Saturday", "Sunday", 
"Thursday", "Tuesday", "Wedesnday"), class = "factor"), working = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, 
20L), class = "data.frame", .Names = c("id", "hours", "dayweek", 
"working"))
```

alternative data of same problem

```
dt = structure(list(X = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 29L, 30L, 
31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 57L, 58L, 59L, 60L, 61L, 62L, 63L, 
64L), id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), hours = c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), dayweek = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Friday", "Monday", "Saturday", 
"Sunday", "Thursday", "Tuesday", "Wedesnday"), class = "factor"), 
working = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), class = "data.frame",   row.names = c(NA, 
-24L), .Names = c("X", "id", "hours", "dayweek", "working"))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could use `data.table` to do this.  We convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`).  Grouped by the 'id' and 'dayweek', we get the numeric index of elements in 'working' which is equal to 1 ('tmp') on `if` there is atleast an 1 value in the group (`if(any(working==1))`). Get the sequence  (`:`) between first (`head(tmp,1)`) and last (`tail(tmp, 1)`) position and wrap it with `.I` to get the row index ('i1').  Use the index and assign the 'working' elements corresponding to that row as 1.

```
library(data.table)
i1 <- setDT(df1)[, if(any(working==1)){tmp <- which(working==1)
                  .I[head(tmp,1):tail(tmp,1)]} , by = .(id, dayweek)]$V1

df1[i1, working:=1L]
df1
#    id hours dayweek working
# 1:  1     1  Friday       0
# 2:  1     2  Friday       0
# 3:  1     3  Friday       0
# 4:  1     4  Friday       0
# 5:  1     5  Friday       0
# 6:  1     6  Friday       0
# 7:  1     7  Friday       0
# 8:  1     8  Friday       1
# 9:  1     9  Friday       1
#10:  1    10  Friday       1
#11:  1    11  Friday       1
#12:  1    12  Friday       1
#13:  1    13  Friday       1
#14:  1    14  Friday       1
#15:  1    15  Friday       1
#16:  1    16  Friday       1
#17:  1    17  Friday       1
#18:  1    18  Friday       0
#19:  1    19  Friday       0
#20:  1    20  Friday       0
```

---

Or a similar solution using `dplyr` (as suggested by @David Arenburg) would be to group by 'id', 'dayweek' columns, use the `min` and `max` to get the first and last positions where `working == 1`, and `replace` those elements in `working` with 1.  If there are no 1 value for a particular group, we can wrap with `ifelse` to return 0 for those group.

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   group_by(id, dayweek) %>%
   mutate(new = any(working ==1),
      working = ifelse(new, replace(working,
                  min(which(working == 1)):max(which(working == 1)), 1), 
                  as.numeric(new))) %>%
   select(-new)
#Source: local data frame [20 x 4]
#Groups: id, dayweek
#
#   id hours dayweek working
#1   1     1  Friday       0
#2   1     2  Friday       0
#3   1     3  Friday       0
#4   1     4  Friday       0
#5   1     5  Friday       0
#6   1     6  Friday       0
#7   1     7  Friday       0
#8   1     8  Friday       1
#9   1     9  Friday       1
#10  1    10  Friday       1
#11  1    11  Friday       1
#12  1    12  Friday       1
#13  1    13  Friday       1
#14  1    14  Friday       1
#15  1    15  Friday       1
#16  1    16  Friday       1
#17  1    17  Friday       1
#18  1    18  Friday       0
#19  1    19  Friday       0
#20  1    20  Friday       0
```

Or a compact option suggested by @Khashaa where we multiply the `cummax` of 'working' with `cummax` of reverse (`rev`) of 'working' so that only elements that are `1` in both the `vectors` remain as 1 while others will be replaced by 0.

```
df1 %>% 
    group_by(id, dayweek) %>%
    mutate(working = cummax(working)*rev(cummax(rev(working))))
```

Comment: very nice - what would be the `dplyr` equivalent ?

Comment: @glacomoV I am working on a dplyr solution.  But, do you have multiple 1s i.e. more than 2 for each id

Comment: no each `id` worked maximum once a day `dayweek`. Each worked days `dayweek` will have maximum 2 values. The start time of work and the end time. Thanks

Comment: Try `(cummax(x)>=max(x))*(rev(cummax(rev(x)))>=max(x))`

Comment: @Khashaa  That is a better one.  You should post it.

Comment: Or maybe `df %>% 
  group_by(id, dayweek) %>%
  mutate(working = replace(working, min(which(working == 1)):max(which(working == 1)), 1))`

Comment: @DavidArenburg I was also thinking about `replace`.  Thanks

Comment: @DavidArenburg Just replace `x` with `working`.  It works

Comment: Hmm.. looks like awfully complicated formula there

Comment: @DavidArenburg, ditto:). I am making the things unnecessarily complicated. Meanwhile, a slightly simpler formula `cummax(x)*rev(cummax(rev(x)))`.

Comment: why not `dta %>% group_by(dayweek) %>% mutate(working = cumsum(working)%%2) ` ?

Comment: @jeremycg the last `1` becomes `0`

Comment: @Khashaa If you are not posting that as a solution, can I add this to my `list` of solutions?

Comment: I get a really strange error message `Error: result would be too long a vector` when I run it on a bigger sample

Comment: can I upload a bigger sample ?

Comment: @glacomoV sure, you can upload a bigger sample in dropbox. I would check if the original data is not similar to the example.

Comment: @akrun I just edited a new dataset that shows the error. For example when I run the code from line `1:16` it works but `1:17` it doesn't. I am not sure what is the problem. thanks !

Comment: @giacomoV If `working` is composed solely of 0s, `which(working == 1)` fails. Have you tried the last option?

Comment: @giacomoV  I guess it should work now.  As Khashaa mentioned, the groups with only 0s were the problematic part.  For the 1st two solutions, I created a logical index to fix the problem.  Khashaa's method does work in both the datasets.